# Converting from JSON to SQL with Python: Suggested libraries/techniques to look into?

Tags: python, sql, json

Yeah, I've seen a bit of SQL-to-JSON but not much talk about going the other way. I guess my question is threefold:

Would I be reinventing the wheel to make a tool which does this?
Are there good libraries that I should look into for making this?
Are there any particular techniques or idioms involved in efficiently and concisely dealing with SQL and/or JSON that I should be aware of?

As usual, thanks for any and all input.

Comment: Maybe you can add some context or an example...unless it's within the context of some web framework, I can't see how going either way really makes sense.  How would it be used?

Comment: @Gerrat: I would like to take a bunch of data that is currently in json files and output it either as a series of SQL commands (to insert all of it into a database while maintaining structure) or simply perform those SQL commands.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the JSON contains some SQL is pretty irrelevant.

It sounds like you just want to read the files containing JSON strings.  You can use the *json* module from the standard python library ( http://docs.python.org/library/json.html ) to read a string into a python variable.

```
import json
var = json.loads(your_string)
```

After that, all you have to do is take the SQL strings and run them using whatever python database driver corresponds to your database.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Pypi? There are several libararies/packages and I am sure you can find something.  http://pypi.python.org/pypi

as Gerrat suggested if you are using a framework then it might have something as well. If not the Python packages are your best bet to find what you need. If you cant find in either of these places, there are code snippet section for your framework of choice or the python sites.

so you have several choices. All you need to do is jfgi ^^